# Finding $P(X\geq Y+0.5)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint PDF
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}3y,\hspace{6mm}-1\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq |x|\\0, \hspace{7mm} \text { otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ I have found the marginals given by
$$\begin{align}f_X(x) &= \begin{cases}\frac{3x^2}{2},\hspace{6mm}x\in [-1, 1]\\0, \hspace{9mm} \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\\f_Y(y) &= \begin{cases}6y(1-y),\hspace{6mm}y\in [0, 1]\\0, \hspace{20mm} \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}.
\end{align}$$
Also, I have identified the area of integration as highlighted in the following figure

[image: the figure].

Now I evaluate the following
$$P(X\geq Y+0.5)=\int_{y=0}^{0.5}\int_{x=y+0.5}^{1}\frac{3x^2}{2}dxdy=\frac{17}{128}.$$ But the expected answer is $\frac{1}{16}$. Is my area of integration and /or integral wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct interval, but the integrand needs to be the *joint* probability density function.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geqslant Y+0.5)&=\iint_{x\geq y+0.5} f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d (x,y)\\[1ex]&=\int_0^{0.5}\int_{y+0.5}^1 3y~\mathrm d x~\mathrm dy\\[1ex] &= \dfrac 1{16}\end{align}$$

Comment: oh yes, how did I miss that, thanks a lot